# How to take input from one function and use it to make a coroutine?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, telethon

I have one function (func1) which checks if an event happened. And if event happened , run another function asynchronous. and again repeat the same.. . (I might not have explained it vary well, so take this code)

```
async def func1(args):
    #check for an event in a while loop with await statements
async def func2(args):
    #main function to do something...
    #this function is also under a while loop with await statements
```

What I want to do is to run func2 for each event separately using asyncio. So, I have created another function.

```
async def func3():
    await asyncio.gather(func2(args))
```

I don't know much about asyncio. I tried to google and found something about `asyncio.Queue()` .
So, Let me summarize it. I want to check for an event in a loop and whenever that event happens I want to run a func2 for it asynchronously and then again check for event (while func2 is still running) and if event again happens run func2 for that event separately.
How do I link these functions together to do the needful..?
**Purpose** : I want to take bot token from user and run a separate bot with that token.

Comment: Any reason you're not using telethons built-in methods to work with events ? (i.e. this https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html )

Comment: I want to take bot token from user and run a separate bot with that token. How can I use inbuilt modules for that..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `create_task` for starting new tasks "in parallel". For example:

```
async def func1(args):
    ...
    if event_happened:
        asyncio.create_task(func2(args))
    ...

async def func2():
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Alex..! , It works the way I want. Do you have any idea how many tasks can be created using this method (shouldn't degrade the performance)..?

Comment: @Mayank You can create as many tasks as you need. Unlike a thread, an asyncio task doesn't consume OS-level resources other than a little bit of memory for bookeeping.